# Python append tkinter widget to list shows as int value

Tags: python, arrays, list, tkinter, append

I'm trying to make an array/list of tkinter Labels for a wage calculator, but whenever I append the widget to my array, it appends as an int datatype. I was thinking appending it would allow me to call list[widgetIndex].grid() but since it wasn't a Label datatype getting appended to my list for some reason, it gives me an error saying that this 'int' object has no attribute called 'grid'. Why is it an int datatype as oppose to the Label datatype that the variable definitely was before I appended it?

```
def addJob(jc, cc, he, wl, hl, we):
    jc = jc + 1
    cc = cc + 2

    wageLabel = Label(root, text="Wage")
    hoursLabel = Label(root, text="Hours")
    wageEntry = Entry(root)
    hoursEntry = Entry(root)

    wl.append(wageLabel)
    hl.append(hoursLabel)
    we.append(wageEntry)
    he.append(hoursEntry)

    wl[jc-1].grid(row =0, column =cc-1, sticky=E)
    hl[jc-1].grid(row =1, column =cc-1, sticky=E)
    we[jc-1].grid(row = 0, column=cc)
    he[jc-1].grid(row = 1, column=cc)
```

Comment: I tried appending a `Label` into a `list` and when I called tried printing its type I got `<class 'tkinter.Label'>`. Can you tell me how to reproduce your error? EDIT: I can even call the `grid` function.

Comment: It looks like `jc` does not correspond to the last element in each `list`, which should be the appropriate widgets. Print out the length of each `list`, along with what `jc-1` is.

Comment: jc is the job count, which at first is 1, so - 1 is the 0th index, which I just checked, and jc-1 indeed 0 , and the legnth for the lists are 2 indexes long.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't have the behavior you describe. The code you posted absolutely will append the label objects to the list objects.

Comment: The error says "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attibute 'grid'. I looked it over quite a bit, and you can tell I'm new and I don't know what else to do than to paste a link to my entire code, your patience is appreciated. http://screencast.com/t/ThKNHeVunfEm

Answer (score 0):

You initialize w1 using `w1 = [ 0 ]`.

Later on you just append to `w1`, so your list will be sth. like

`[ 0, <class 'tkinter.Label'>, <class 'tkinter.Label'>, <class 'tkinter.Label'>, ... ]` depending on how many labels you add.

Using `w1 = []` will solve your problem.

The error occurs as the first element in your list ("0") cannot be gridded.

Using `print w1` in your function would have shown you this in a fairly easy way.

Bryan is right, the code you posted is without a doubt okay for the purpose you intend using it, but the initialization for your passed parameters (not posted as code sample) defines a different behaviour.

Please read on [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Breaking down code into the smallest piece still reproducing the error mostly guides you direct to the solution.